# Filter firebase firestore data in react js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to perform a filter and sort query, but I want to put it inside a function. How can I do that ?

I'm trying to do this

```
const handleFilter = () => {
  const q = query(collection(db, "location"), where ("location", "==", "Pasig"));

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    (doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Please be sure to include _how_ it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

To use await keyword inside a function it needs to be declared as an async function. Try the following:

```
const handleFilter = async () => {
const q = query(
  collection(db, "location"),
  where("location", "==", "Pasig")
);

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  doc.id, "=>", doc.data();
});
```